# Problem with datatables and rowgroup - won't collapse/expand more than 2 groups

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have followed some instructions how to apply rowgroup for collapse/expand but the rowgroups won't collapse when more than 2 rowgroups defined:

```
rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: [3,1,2]
            }
```

Here is my example:

http://live.datatables.net/yosigodi/1/edit

does anyone know how to alter the script so more than 2 rowgroups can be used for collapse/expand?

Comment: The docs: [Currently only a single data point can be used for grouping at a time - there is no support for nested grouping](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/#Limitations-and-future-work)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to apply the following script:

http://live.datatables.net/migixiqi/1/edit

And just added an additional third row for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapsedGroups = {};
    var top = '';
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        order: [
            [1, 'asc'],
            [2, 'asc']
        ],
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: [3, 2, 1],
            startRender: function(rows, group, level) {
                var all;

                if (level === 0) {
                    top = group;
                    all = group;
                } else {
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                        return;
                    }
                    all = top + group;
                }

                var collapsed = !!collapsedGroups[all];

                rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                    r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                });

                // Add category name to the <tr>. NOTE: Hardcoded colspan
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                    .attr('data-name', all)
                    .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
            }
        }

    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function() {
        var name = $(this).data('name');

        collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
        table.draw(false);
    });

});
```

But it does not work for more than 2 columns :-/